# Combination of orders and suppliers

Tags: algorithm, combinations

So i have the following situation.

I want to find all possible combination of product order at an amount of suppliers.

Lets say i have 3 products

> - Product G
> - Product S
> - Product X

Now lets say i have 3 suppliers

> - Supplier A
> - Supplier B
> - Supplier C

What are all possible combinations of orders? Im not really a math genius so i tried writing them out (27 combinations):

[image: combinations]

However im at a loss how to calculate this without writing it out like i did.
Im sure there is an algorithm or simple calculation for this.

Comment: You're looking for the [ordered partitions of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Ordered_partitions).  You can generate these recursively by writing a function `part(X)` that, for each possible subset S of the products in the argument set X, calls `part(X-S)`, which returns a list of all possible partitions of the remaining products, and then appends (or prepends) the set S to each of the ordered partitions in this list.  The 1st set in a partition corresponds to the products to get from A, the second to the products to get from B, etc.